# subprocess.Popen success message

Tags: python, windows, operation

Whenever I am spawning the application using the `subprocess.Popen` the Windows command line is being launched for a second containing the message that is saying following: `The operation completed successfully.`

This is really annoying. Is there a way to disable this? Do I have to set the level reporting or what?

Comment: Can you show the offending code?

Comment: @mgilson Its just as simple as... `subprocess.Popen(["application.exe"], env=os.environ.copy(), close_fds=True)` ?

Comment: If you run `application.exe` manually, does the command line pop up, or does it only happen in your code?

Comment: @aquavitae It does only popup when I run my python code containing the `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags=subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen(["application.exe"], env=os.environ.copy(), close_fds=True, startupinfo=si)
```

What it does is tells `Popen` to use specific parameters (defined by the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) object, `si`)  when starting the process.  In this case, it tells it to use `si.wShowWindow` when creating a new window, and the default value of this is [`SW_HIDE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.SW_HIDE), so it hides it.

Comment: `<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 
'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'`

Comment: What version of python are you using?  This worked on 2.7 and according to the docs should work on 3.3.  I assume you tested it on Windows, the constant is only defined on Windows.

Comment: Using the Python 2.7 as well, Windows 8

Comment: I'm on windows 7. Don't know why that should make a difference though.  What do you get from `sys.platform`?

Comment: Looks like something weird with your install.  Have a look at `Python\Lib\subprocess.py`.  Line 392 has `mswindows = (sys.platform == "win32")` and a little further down should be `if mswindows: from _subprocess import ... STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`.  If you try `>>> subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` you should get `1`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44685/discussion-between-aquavitae-and-lucas)